# PostgreSql использование regexp_matches

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

В таблице есть колонка с данными следующего вида:

```
10a.23.45b some text
10.23.45 some text
23.45.67b some text
```

Мне необходимо выделить часть с номером до первого пробела, делаю следующим образом:

```
select regexp_matches(name, '^[0-9].*?[.][0-9].*?[.][0-9].*?[ ]', 'g') from sometable
```

Результат:

```
10a.23.45b 
10.23.45 
23.45.67b
```

Теперь я пытаюсь упростить регулярное выражение заменив на `[0-9].*?[.]){2}`:

```
select regexp_matches(name, '^([0-9].*?[.]){2}[0-9].*?[ ]', 'g') from sometable
```

Но в этом варианте возвращается только до первой точки, не могу понять в чем дело:

```
10a. 
10. 
23.
```

Также не могу понять почему не выводится вся строка если убрать из первого варианта конечный пробел [] вот так `^[0-9].*?[.][0-9].*?[.][0-9].*`. Почему вместо `10a.23.45b some text` возвращается только `10a.23.4`?

Comment: `SELECT regexp_matches(name, '[^ ]+') ..`

Comment: Смотрите https://regex101.com/r/Baw8lb/1.

Comment: @tocic в postgreSql не срабатывает, не могу понять почему

Comment: А так если '^\S+'.